# llenar un formulario automaticamente

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony3

En un input TypeText busco una coincidencia por **nombre** dentro de una tabla en una db de lo que el usuario escribe en dicho input. En el controlador recibo los valores de lo que el usuario escribe (**$term**) de la siguiente manera:

```
public function jqueryWithAction(Request $request)
{
    $names = array();
    $term = trim(strip_tags($request->get('term')));
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

     $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT ts
                FROM TestBundle:Test ts
                    WHERE ts.nombre LIKE :nombre'
        )->setParameter('nombre', "%".$term."%");
        $entities=$query->getResult();

    foreach ($entities as $entity)
    {
        $names[] = $entity->getNombre();
    }

    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData($names);

    return $response;
}
```

del lado del front la función que envía los valores ($term) al controlador es la siguiente:

```
$('.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source: "{{ path('busqueda_jquery') }}",
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group txt">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nombre</label>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    {{ form_widget(form.nombre,{'attr':{'class':'autocomplete'}}) }}
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group txt">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Apellido</label>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
   <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
```

hasta aquí se cumple la búsqueda, la cuestión es que al encontrar dicho valor necesito llenar algunos otros input (vacios y sin clase) con los datos pertenecientes al campo **nombre** que consulte.

Por ejemplo llenar uno o mas input automáticamente con los apellidos (por decir algo) pertenecientes al campo **nombre** que se consultò.

Comment: Deberias incluir tu HTML.

Comment: Ya añadí esa parte.

Comment: Puedes agregar alguna clase al input?

Comment: si, clase o id.. es la idea pero aun no esta desarrollado!

Answer (score 0):

Porque no lo intentas asi:

```
$('.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: "{{ path('busqueda_jquery') }}",
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        $(".apellido").val(suggestion.data);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group txt">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nombre</label>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    {{ form_widget(form.nombre,{'attr':{'class':'autocomplete'}}) }}
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group txt">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Apellido</label>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
   <input type="text" class="form-control apellido">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No veo la diferencia!

Comment: La diferencia es esta linea: `$(".apellido").val(suggestion.data);`.  Ademas agregue una clase al input.

Comment: entiendo, pero no hay manera que el parámetro  __suggestion.data__ me asigne los campos faltantes que hacen referencia a mi consulta.

Comment: Si tienes mas informacion en `suggestion` y tienes mas campos que necesitas llenar, lo harias de la misma manera